# Is there a general formula for infinite series of a rational function

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Is there some sort of formula to calculate $$\sum_x \frac{P_1(x)}{P_2(x)}$$
In particular, what is $$\sum_x \frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}$$
And what is $$\sum_x \frac{1}{x^3+1}$$

Comment: Is there a specific motivation for wanting to calculate these sums? Without more context we cannot help you.

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b},\qquad \psi(z)=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S_p=\sum_{x=0}^p \frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}=\frac 1a\sum_{x=0}^p \frac{1}{(x-r)(x-s)}=\frac 1{a(r-s)}\sum_{x=0}^p \left(\frac 1{x-r}- \frac 1{x-s}\right)$$ Assuming that $r$ and $s$ are not integers, use
$$\sum_{x=0}^p\frac 1{x-t}=\psi (p-t+1)-\psi (-t)$$
$$S_p=\frac{\psi (p-r+1)-\psi(p-s+1)-\psi (-r)+\psi (-s)}{a(r-s)}$$ Now, for large values of $p$, using asymptotics
$$S_p=\frac{\psi (-s)-\psi (-r)}{a (r-s)}-\frac{1}{a p}+\frac{1-r-s}{2 a
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

For the other cases, it is the same story : use partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: What if x starts from 7? For example, $\sum_{n=7}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x+\frac{2}{3}}-\frac{1}{x+5}\right)$

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\sum_{n=7}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x+\frac{2}{3}}-\frac{1}{x-5}\right)$

Comment: @AndrewFount. What does that mean ? What is inside the parentheses is a constant that you add an infinite number of times.

Comment: I just mixed the variables. Sorry, here is the correct one. $\sum_{n=7}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+\frac{2}{3}}-\frac{1}{n-5}\right)$

Comment: When n=5, there is singularity.